# Call Magma in Mathematica

Tags: performance-tuning, export, import, interoperability

I've written some code in *Mathematica*, related to some group theory questions I have.  Subsequently, I found that part of the code could be significantly sped up if I could just call a routine in [Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/magma/).  Is there any way to have *Mathematica* ask Magma to run a subroutine, and then have *Mathematica* use the output?

More specifically, my *Mathematica* code outputs a bunch of relations, such as $a^2=b^2,ab=ca$.  I need to then have Magma run the lines of code:

```
g:=Group<a,b,c|a*a=b*b,a*b=c*a>;n:=Index(g,sub<g|g.1>);n;
```

and then I need *Mathematica* to use the output $n$.

Comment: Can you add a minimal example to clarify what you want to do? This might make answering more efficient.

Comment: Here's a component to use a similar package to magma called GAP: https://github.com/msollami/CodingBlog/blob/CodingBlog/GapLink.nb

Comment: If you don't find a package that already communicates with Magma then you'll have to roll your own.  The simplest way to communicate may be using `StartProcess` and related functions, if these work well with Magma and if Magma accepts piped input.  The other option is to use MathLink to link them up.  MathLink has official C, Java and .NET APIs.  Doing this *will* be a lot of work (expect several days in the least), so I would definitely start with controlling the magma process using `StartProcess`.

Comment: @M.R. Your link is dead now. Do you still have this?