# How to call the function calculation result of Magma in MMA

Tags: interoperability, external-calls

[Magma](http://magma.maths.usyd.edu.au/calc/) is a very useful abstract algebra calculation software.How to 
call the function calculation result of magma in MMA?

```
R < x > := PolynomialRing (RationalField ());
f := x^10 - 1280/512*x^8 + 1120/512*x^6 - 400/512*x^4 + 50/512*x^2 - 1/512;
GaloisGroup (f);
```

[image]

```
f[x_] := x^10 - 1280/512*x^8 + 1120/512*x^6 - 400/512*x^4 + 
   50/512*x^2 - 1/512;
galoisGroup[
 f[x], x](*How to receive the result from the magma and pass it to \
the PermutationGroup function*)
```

Comment: Do you want this to happen automatically or are you fine with copy-pasting the string and then parsing that?

Comment: I want this to happen automatically.

Comment: Then it’d be nice to know how one calls into Magma using something other than a web interface. If you can give us more info we have a better chance of doing this.

Comment: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103602/call-magma-in-mathematica and https://github.com/msollami/CodingBlog/blob/CodingBlog/GapLink.nb

Comment: that thing doesn’t provide any calling mechanism. Can you at least provide the way you’d call Magma from the command line?

Comment: I don't know that at the moment. I only use magma from the web.

Comment: If you can show us how that is done we can help you write a Mathematica wrapper

Comment: Now I can only think of using functions like `URLFetch` or  `SocketConnect` to achieve my goal.

Comment: Presumably you can get Magma as a command line program too? If that’s the case this is very doable

Comment: But at present, I will not use these functions to achieve the goal, so I put forward related questions.